# how web service orchestration is possible via java program

Tags: java, jquery, web-services, orchestration

Helo all.
I am doing my final year project in java web service.
I am developing a graphical user interface for orchestration tool.  In which web services are to be combined and then needs to be testing in another testing gui tool.
Now, i have no idea in which format, i have to combine the service and then test it.
Please suggest me a way, or language, or any ideas please.  it will be more helpful for me. 
thank you.

Comment: This site is there to help you with **specific** code issues you encounter, and not to do the thinking and experimenting for you. Please try something and ask here if you encounter a **specific** problem!

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc, i am sorry.  I cannot able to upvote as i have not meet the requirement to do up vote(mark as useful)..

Comment: I would past some code up for questions. I think that i would show some examples or even some code.

Comment: Hello @DougHauf sir.  It would be very helpful for me to get some ideas if you show some examples.  Meanwhile i got some idea, please suggest me whether it is relevant. Drag and drop using jquery, which will generate xml file which contains list of composed web services.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take the task definition and try to refactor it and cut it down to a list of **needs** and **functionalities**. It'll then be easier for you to determine what *resources* and *tools* you need, and how to attack the problem.

If you need ideas for your project, take a look at this: [Brainstorming guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549469/need-ideas-for-an-interesting-android-based-final-year-project/16549740#16549740)

Comment: @venki I did not link the page for an upvote, I linked it because you asked for ideas, and I think this is a pretty good guideline to come up with ideas.

Comment: @venki To me, it looks like it's unclear for you what you have to accomplish for that project, and how to do it (correct me if I'm wrong). Take the time to do a rigorous analysis of the task instead of diving head first into it.

Comment: I feel your guidelines are totally irrelevant to my question.  I would suggest you not answer for questions that is totally irrelevant for your knowledge.  I have project ideas and i need a way to make a start in it, 1 answer from this site triggers me to think 100 ideas.

Comment: @venki Well, sorry for answering to what you asked: `Please suggest me a way, or language, or any ideas please.` - You. If you want answers relevant to your question, please make a clear and understandable question...

Comment: For my question, you may answer like, "You may try bpel language", or any language.  or use any tools for orchestration.  its very very hard to work with web service, but i am in very deep concepts in web service.  its very pleasure to get answers from users.  And don't make disappoint by posting advices.

Comment: @venki `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` - Help Center. Do you expect us to do the thinking job for you?

Comment: @venki In that way, you should have formed your question like: `I'm developing a Java application with web services... I have implemented this (code)... I'm having trouble with this, what approach would you suggest for that specific part?`

Comment: @venki But that's **too broad**! What kind of web services is the application offering? What kind of tests are to be ran? What **code, mockup or specs** can you show us to better determine the context of your application?

Comment: its restful web service.  I just developed in netbeans.  And i need to combine several service in my project interface and then need to test the combined service.  the web service has to communicate each other.